# Jquery toggle along with read more button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a toggle effect, when pressing Read More button, but on example I have here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9XK3/2/) the toggle is working ok, what I want to change is that when pressing the button, information from 
`<div class="answer">`
to appear above the button, not under, so when pressing read more, the button will slide down also.

How can I do that? as I don't have any ideas for now... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put answer above the button and use `prev` function.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9XK3/4/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to swap the order of the answer and the button and then change the jQuery.

```
$('.answer').slideToggle(500);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can swap the order of your button and `.answer`in your HTML markup:

```
<div class="answer">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
        adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod
        tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
        volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
        nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
        lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="READ MORE" id="readmore">
```

then use:

```
$(this).prev().slideToggle(500);
```

instead of:

```
$(this).next('.answer').slideToggle(500);
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9XK3/12/)**

Answer (score 1):

Do that   **Working here** http://jsfiddle.net/nc72a/

Note: remove the margin from p (.answer p{margin:0;}) so it will not fluctuate...

**HTML**

```
<div class="answer">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
            adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod
            tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
            volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
            nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
            lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="READ MORE" id="readmore">
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#readmore').click(function() {
     $(this).prev('.answer').slideToggle(500);
     $(this).toggleClass('close');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to reinvent the wheel, there's a jquery plugin for that http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/demo/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is order of element.
Put `<div clsss='answer'>` above the button.

here check out this : http://jsfiddle.net/n9XK3/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#readmore').click(function() {

                $(this).prev('.answer').slideToggle(500);
                $(this).toggleClass('close');

            });
        }); // end ready
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the submit button after the answer div and change this jQuery line

```
$(this).next('.answer').slideToggle(500);
```

for this

```
$(this).prev().slideToggle(500);
```

because the button will be after the div instead of before.

Answer (score 0):

here is http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/qECA6/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#readmore').click(function() {

                   if( ! $('.answer').is(':visible') )
                      $('.answer').slideDown(500);
                    else
                       $('.answer').slideUp(500);

               });
           }); 

     </script>



    <section id="faq-list">
        <h5>Is it true that you are a carrot?</h5>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
            adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod
            tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
            volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
            nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
            lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
        <div class="answer" style='display:none;'>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
                adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod
                tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
                volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
                nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
                lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="READ MORE" id="readmore">
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle. just change the order of elements.

```
   [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/n9XK3/21/
```